# Best way to multi-thread?

Tags: c, multithreading

What is the best way to multi-thread in the C language? I want something that is very efficient and not a CPU hog. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct (standard) way to do this on C and Windows is with [__beginthreadex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx).

This is usually preferred to calling [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx) directly as CreateThread doesn't init C runtime support for the thread. So if you create a thread using CreateThread, and call a CRT function, bad stuff can/will happen.

Note that __beginthreadex calls CreateThread internally, but performs some other work behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a UNIX-based platform (Linux or Mac OS X) your best option is [POSIX threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads). They're the standard cross-platform way to multithread in a POSIX environment. They can also be used in Windows, but there are probably better (more native) solutions for that platform.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit general to answer effectively. You might look into such things as:

CreateThread in the windows SDK

boost::thread